# android layout messed up on the phone

Tags: android, layout

I did my layout based on emulator but just ran my app on an actual device and all the layout is messed up. I don't know how to fix it. here is the code for my xml file,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/mainback" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="255dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="276dp"
        android:layout_height="132dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="some text"
        android:textColor="#4C2016"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/special"
        android:layout_width="131dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cc"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Specials"
        android:textColor="#F6E6C6" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`

It would be awesome is some one can tell me how to fix this code

Here is snap shot of what it looks like on the xml file

[image]

This is how it looks like on the phone,

[image]

The image and the text in orange are part of the background image and the textview and the button are added to the view.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the poor layout on the phone?  Can you tell us exactly what is wrong with the layout as compared to the emulator?

Comment: You have to define "messed up" otherwise ... we have no idea what "messed up" means.

Comment: Can you post what exactly is messed up, and how must it look?

Comment: Why on earth do you have all those hard-coded dimensions in your layout?

Answer (score 0):

Which API level are you using?
Because I see you are using "fill_parent" and "match_parent" in the same file. Starting from API level 8, fill_parent is replaced with math_parent.
I also had problems with using match_parent in a project with API level lower than 8 (which isn't recognized") and visa versa fill_parent gives me layout problems in a project with API 8 or higher.

But to better help you, please post some screenshots of your running APP. So, we can better see what are your layout problems.

Have nice development!

Answer (score 0):

The hardcoded values makes the layout look different depending on device screensize and resolution.

Instead of depending on margin to have the text below your image ('android:layout_marginTop="255dip") you could put the image in an ImageView'. Your TextView will then be positioned below the image. Fine tune distance using bottom margin on the imageview or top margin on the textview.

Use 'wrap_content' for *layout_height* of the TextView and 'fill_parent' for *layout_width* instead of fixed values.

Also - replace 'match_parent' with 'fill_parent' if your application is targeted for API lower than 8.

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ImageView/>
    <TextView/>
    <Button/>
</LinearLayout>
```